Angular HttpClient POST request with body false send without payload
When I'm sending POST requests in my Angular application with the body beeing a boolean, in the case it is true it is correctly send in the payload, in the case it is false no payload is send with the request.
constructor(
    public readonly http: HttpClient,
  ) {
  const requestBody = false;
  http.request({
      method: 'POST',
      url: '/locked',
      body: requestBody,
      mediaType: 'application/json',
    });
}

Is there a way to send boolean base types directly with false value?

Perhaps just send the text "false": requestBody = 'false'?. You probably also need to set the content-type header to application/json.

Thanks, that actually works. Though I'm not sure how I like it from a type safety standpoint. In my specific case (where the BE is unabled to accomodate a JSON object solution) it is a great workarround though!

You should send a parameter inside the POST body, like this :

const requestBody = {value : false};

And then retrieve the value param in your target API endpoint.

Thanks, sadly I don't have control over the API. Do you have any reference regarding if booleans generally should not be send directly in the body for application/json? I'm stuck in the discussion with the BE maintainer and that could help.

Post requests should be a body, not just a parameter, maybe you can use this link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/26717908/12927815 Otherwise you can switch to a GET endpoint and pass the param via URL.

I found out that I mistakenly thought I'm working directly with the Angular httpClient, however I overlooked some magic by our OpenAPI client generator (openapi-typescript-codegen). Actually the request was wrapped by the client and what I thought was correctly setting the content-type to 'application/json' didn't set it at all. When I instead manually send the request with this content-type a false is correctly send as false and our BE works as expected.
